# use linq to get a sub list that contains elements from an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have tried various version of this but I am just off somewhere.
I am using Teleric Raddropdowncheckedlist

```
var states = stateDropDownList.CheckedItems.ToList();
var filteredStops = (from stop in aDb.Stop_address_details 
                     where states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) select stop).ToList();
```

States contains a array of IL, AL etc.
Here is the sample data from states - in the debugger it says states count 3, it has 3 elements 0=AZ, 1=IL and 2=AL.

stop_address_details contains the field stop_state.

I just need records where the stop_state is included in states.

I am not getting a result because it wont build - error:
The number of parameters of this lamda expression does not match the number of paramenters of delegate.

Solution:

```
var states = stateDropDownList.CheckedItems.Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).ToList();
        var filteredStops = (from stop in aDb.Stop_address_details where states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) select stop).ToList();
```

The original states was returning a array of items, not strings.
Thank you for the help.
Joe

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the results you are getting?

Comment: The linq query that you have should work if the states is a list of strings! what's the issue? Maybe there is trim() or Lower/Upper case issue?

Comment: Don't know what dropdown list you are using, but any decent one would have an DropDownListItemsCollection (or whatever called) collection under that CheckedItems. So states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) would be a no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
var states = stateDropDownList.CheckedItems.Select(i=>i.Value.ToString()).ToList();
```

That `i.Value` bit is very dependent on what DropDownList you are using. And is not guaranteed to work if CheckedItems is a custom collection type which doesn't implement standard interfaces, either.

Comment: Thank you...it just goes to show that the place where the error is at is not always the place to look.

Comment: You're welcome. And a piece of advice: try using the lambda linq querying. Intellisense is way more helpful that way. The tricky part is understanding them lambdas very well.